# Error running the initialised React Native project in Xcode

Tags: ios, react-native

After installing react-native and running the newly created Xcode project I am getting the following output:

```
2015-03-26 15:35:05.865 React[1427:7950] CLTilesManagerClient: initialize, sSharedTilesManagerClient
2015-03-26 15:35:05.865 React[1427:7950] CLTilesManagerClient: init
2015-03-26 15:35:05.866 React[1427:7950] CLTilesManagerClient: reconnecting, 0x7fac1b289e40
RCTJSLog> "Running application "React" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF"
RCTJSLog> "Error: 
 stack: 
  React_render                                       index.ios.bundle:955
  _renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext     index.ios.bundle:16453
  _renderValidatedComponent                          index.ios.bundle:16479
  ReactCompositeComponent__renderValidatedComponent  index.ios.bundle:4860
  mountComponent                                     index.ios.bundle:15913
  ReactCompositeComponent_mountComponent             index.ios.bundle:4860
  mountComponent                                     index.ios.bundle:4929
  mountComponentIntoNode                             index.ios.bundle:15386
  perform                                            index.ios.bundle:5992
  batchedMountComponentIntoNode                      index.ios.bundle:15405
  perform                                            index.ios.bundle:5992
  batchedUpdates                                     index.ios.bundle:13507
  batchedUpdates                                     index.ios.bundle:4524
  renderComponent                                    index.ios.bundle:15457
  ReactMount__renderNewRootComponent                 index.ios.bundle:4860
  render                                             index.ios.bundle:1155
  renderApplication                                  index.ios.bundle:33797
  run                                                index.ios.bundle:33743
  runApplication                                     index.ios.bundle:33765
  jsCall                                             index.ios.bundle:7149
  _callFunction                                      index.ios.bundle:7396
  applyWithGuard                                     index.ios.bundle:877
  guardReturn                                        index.ios.bundle:7198
  callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue                     index.ios.bundle:7405
 URL: http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle
 line: 955
 message: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'React.createElement(Text, {style: styles.welcome}, 
          "Welcome to React Native!"
        )')"
```

Any help figuring out why this is failing would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Was able to fix the simulator error by running 'npm start' in the react directory. Now having an issue testing on a USB connected iPhone.

Getting this error:
Could not connect to development server. Ensure node server is running - run 'npm start' from React root

The operation couldn't be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error - 1004.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run on a device (which is your second problem), take a look at these comments from the React Native examples:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/Movies/Movies/AppDelegate.m

> To run on device, change `localhost` to the IP address of your
>   computer, and make sure your computer and iOS device are on the same
>   Wi-Fi network.

I think this is because the application needs to connect to the packager. See if that helps.